# How to make python in template to enter if condition only once

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a some products and some pictures of in different models. While displaying all products I need to display 1 image in the table. I tried this:

**template :**

```
{% for instance in instances %}
    <tr class="check_items_row">
        <td style="width:20px;">
           <div class="checkbox lgi-checkbox m-t-5">
              <label>
                  <input class="check check_item" type="checkbox" value="{{instance.pk}}" name="delete_item">
                  <i class="input-helper"></i>
              </label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'products:product' pk=instance.pk %}">{{instance.auto_id}}</a></td>
        <td>{{instance.category}}</td>
        <td>{{instance.subcategory}}</td>
        <td>{{instance.name}}</td>
        {% for item in product_gallery %}
            {% if item.product == instance and test == 0 %}
                <td><img src="{{item.image.url}}" alt="Image" style="width:100px;"/></td>
             {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def products(request):
    instances = Product.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).order_by('auto_id')
    product_gallery = ProductGallery.objects.all()
    context = {
        'title': "Product ",
        'instances' : instances,
        "product_gallery": product_gallery,
        "test": 0,
    }
    return render(request,'products/products.html',context)
```

in my thoughts I just need to change the value of test in template if it enters the *if condition once* .

**This code is displaying all images of a product.**  I just need one image of every product.

Here i will need to change the value inside `if` condition and reset to 0 after the `for` loop

**models:**

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey('products.ProductCategory',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey('products.ProductSubCategory',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products_product'
        verbose_name = _('product')
        verbose_name_plural = _('products')
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name


class ProductGallery(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='products/product_gallery/')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products_product_gallery'
        verbose_name = _('product_gallery')
        verbose_name_plural = _('product_gallerys')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return(self.product)
```

Comment: Please show your Models

Comment: why dont you slice your queryset? product_gallery = ProductGallery.objects.all()[0]

Comment: it return this error:  `'ProductGallery' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_image_url(self):
        img = self.productgallery_set.first()
        if img:
            return img.image.url
        return img #None
```

Add this under your product model and call get_image_url in your templates

Comment: before adding it can I ask you what is `productgallery_set` is?

Comment: This is reverse look up, since both tables connected through FK

Answer (score 1):

Hi Add this code below `Prodect Model`

```
def get_first_image(self):
  try:
     img =  ProductGallery.objects.filter(product=self.id).first()
     if img:
         return img.image.url
     else: 
        return " "
  except:
        return " "
```

in template call it as `<img src="{{ instances.get_first_image }}">`

Comment: This returns an underscore as `src` and i tried to print `url` : it returns `get_rendered`

Comment: yes I have some images in the database the first code i tried displays all of those images. I just need one of them